# Split list of string to list of map

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have the following list
`[12_223,13_4356,15_5676]`

I was able to spilt on underscore and convert this into one Hashmap using the below code

```
list.stream()
    .map(s -> s.split("_"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        a -> a[0],
        a -> a[1]));
```

it gives the below map
`{"12"="223", "13"="4356", "15"="5676"}`

But I wanted to change this code so that it gives me a list of maps like below as I might encounter duplicate keys while splitting

`[{"12"="223"}, {"13"="4356"}, {"15"="5676"}]`

Comment: Why do you want a list of maps?  What's wrong with the single map?

Comment: @rgettman I might get duplicate keys

Comment: @Jeyaprakash Put that information in the question please, as it may be important aspect while suggesting answers.

Comment: Anyway in that case wouldn't map of lists `Map<String, List<String>>` be more appropriate? What is your goal?

Comment: Holy shit Java syntax changed so much since the last version! It's trying to be more like Ruby! In Ruby: `list.map{|v| v.split('_')}.map{|k,v| {k=>v}}` yields `[{"12"=>"223"}, {"13"=>"4356"}, {"15"=>"5676"}]`.

Comment: Why not keep it as 2-element arrays in a `List<String[]>`? Or make a `List<Entry<String,String>>` using `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(k, v)`. You don't need an entire `Map` object for each pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want the result to be a list of maps, I'd do it this way:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .map(s -> s.split("_", 2))
               .map(a -> Collections.singletonMap(a[0], a[1]))
               .collect(toList());
}
```

(HT: Eugene for recommending `split("_", 2)`.)

In Java 9, you could do it this way:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
               .map(s -> s.split("_", 2))
               .map(a -> Map.of(a[0], a[1]))
               .collect(toList());
}
```

In both cases, the map instances in the resulting list will be unmodifiable.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you are looking for

```
List<Map<String, String>> output = list.stream().map(
s-> {
        Map<String, String> element = new HashMap<>();
        String[] arr = s.split("_");
        element.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
        return element;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But as @Pshemo suggests, this should be more appropriate

```
    Map<String, List<String>> outputnew = list.stream().map(
            s -> s.split("_"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0],  
                    Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: what if the input has many "_"... you probably what `s -> split("_", 2)`...